Error 500 while creating Azure DevOps server connector in Microsoft teams
when trying to configure the Azure DevOps server connector in Microsoft Teams it gives an error in the inspect and gives an empty page as a response :
I have been attempting from the web client and the app and restarted it and re-login from different devices all the same


I can reproduce the same error when configuring the Azure DevOps Server Connector in Microsoft Teams.
After checking the official document of Azure DevOps integration with Microsoft Teams, I found a Note under Add the Azure DevOps Server app to a team:

Office 365 Connectors within Teams are being retired, and new Office 365 Connector creation might be blocked. For more information, see Retirement of Office 365 connectors within Microsoft Teams. If you can't access the Connectors page from within the Teams desktop client, try using the Teams web client. The Workflows app in Teams provides similar functionality with better scalability and security.

We can see that it is sending requests to the Office 365 connector. It appears that the creation of new Office 365 connectors is now blocked.

It is recommended not to use the Azure DevOps Server app in Microsoft Teams as it is being retired.
